# How to correctly update a child component React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to ReactJS, and I am trying to conform myself its style of programming! It's a challenge, but definitely fun!

I am making an admin console of sorts. There are two pages to navigate through on a sidemenu, and I wanted to know if I'm handling this in a "React" way.

[Console Page Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Io02.png)

For the sake of simplicity, here is relevant pseudo code for displaying the correct content page.

```
export class Console extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         < ... Sidemenu Content ... />
         <ContentWrapper >
            {this.getContent()}
         </ContentWrapper
      );
}
```

I'm calling a function `this.getContent()` that returns, based on the console's state, a component to put inside of "ContentWrapper".

1. Is this the "correct" or at least a "good" way of handling components?
2. The child's size depends on a state in the console. This state changes every time the window is resized, and the size is passed in as a prop to the child in `this.getContent()`. Is calling `this.getContent()` inefficient? Is it re-rendering a new child component every time, instead of updating the child that is already there?

**EDIT**

```
  // Based on the key, returns the content to display to the user.
  getContent(key) {
    var newContent = null;
    switch (key) {
      case Sidemenu.map:
        newContent = <p>"Map"</p>
        break;
      case Sidemenu.team:
        newContent = <TeamManager size={this.state.contentHeight - 48}/>
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return newContent;
  }
```

Sorry if my question is convoluted, I'm trying my best to used ReactJS lingo!

Thanks!

Connor

Comment: Each time the state is updated, if the render depend of the state all the component and his childrens are re-rendered...

Comment: I'm passing in the parent's state as a prop to the child, so setting the state does not inherently propagate the child's props. The call to `this.getContent()` returns the child with the state passed in as a prop. Is this the correct way to handle it? Would it be better to have the parent communicate with the child via a listener function of sorts? I don't know the actual term for that.

Comment: Can you add your `getContent` function to your question, plz?

Comment: Added getContent() :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do a conditional rendering, it's cleaner and it could be something like this:

```
 <ContentWrapper>
 { 
  this.state.Sidemenu.map? <p>Map</p>:
  <TeamManager size={this.state.contentHeight - 48}/>
 }
 </ContentWrapper
```

** I'm assuming Sidemenu is part of your state and is not null or undefined

For this case to be specific you render whatever you want in that case with an inline "if"

Comment: This seems like a good solution for the immediate case, but assume my menu grows beyond. It could get mess ycould it not?

Comment: well, in that case, it would be a better option to have a switch but I'd encapsulate "that switch" within the menu since is the responsible to conditionally render a specific option something like <Menu type={this.state.Sidemenu}>

Comment: Good tip and I'll be sure to restructure it to reflect that. However, I'm still struggling with the 2nd point I made. About updating the content with the parent's size.

Comment: pass the info as props something like this <Menu type={this.state.Sidemenu} contentHeight={this.state.contentHeight} /> then every time your state changes will re-render the child component, you can set the info of the state in the constructor or componentWillMount if this is an API call